# The errors of neo4j-manual-milestone.pdf

Tags: neo4j

These codes are in neo4j-manual-milestone.pdf( version: 1.8M05):

```
    TraversalDescription t = new TraversalDescription();
    t.setOrder( TraversalDescription.DEPTH_FIRST );
    t.setUniqueness( TraversalDescription.NODE );
    t.setMaxDepth( 10 );
    t.setReturnFilter( TraversalDescription.ALL );
    t.setRelationships( new Relationship( "singer", Relationship.OUT ) );
    // END SNIPPET: traversalDesc

    // START SNIPPET: traverse
    URI traverserUri = new URI( startNode.toString() + "/traverse/node" );
    WebResource resource = Client.create()
            .resource( traverserUri );
    String jsonTraverserPayload = t.toJson();
    ClientResponse response = resource.accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
            .type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
            .entity( jsonTraverserPayload )
            .post( ClientResponse.class );

    System.out.println( String.format(
            "POST [%s] to [%s], status code [%d], returned data: "
                    + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ) + "%s",
            jsonTraverserPayload, traverserUri, response.getStatus(),
            response.getEntity( String.class ) ) );
    response.close();
```

When I use them, the errors display.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the online version of the manual, at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8.M05/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html at the bottom of the page there is a link to the full source, which is executed and tested together with the main neo4j build.

HTH